# GRPC intermittent connection, read ECONNRESE error

Tags: node.js, nestjs, grpc, grpc-node

Unfortunately i cannot provide much code due to the nature of the programme (not owned by me). I have an issue where I have 9 microservices all written with `NestJs` these microservices work fine locally however when i deploy them to a live network (made up of docker containers) 2 of the servers will sporadically get `14 UNAVAILABLE: read ECONNRESE` errors. This issue does not seem to happen with all other services

i am using

```
Node: 16-alpine3.11

"@nestjs/microservices": "^8.0.6",
"@grpc/grpc-js": "^1.3.7", 
"@grpc/proto-loader": "^0.6.5",
```

I am mainly confused why this issue only happens on a live docker environment (when i mean live i mean running over a docker network).

does anyone have any sort of idea why this would be (offer explanation as to why these connection errors happen) or any suggestions on how i can debug it. My initial thoughts are that it may be to do with packages, either an incompatibility or version issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this my by affected issue by node, take a look a this thread https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/1907

The proposition is that to downgrade node ver to 16.8.0

Comment: ill give it a try, see what happens, and report back, thanks.

Comment: @JayP any feedback?

Comment: I have seen that downgrading has worked for someone on this thread. I tried to do the same and downgraded all my docker containers to node `16.8.0` but it did not work for me. I left some feedback on the thread. 

It was suggested to me to create a client interceptor to retry requests, so i am now just giving this a try. It does not solve the underlying issue which is worrying me about putting my solution into prod but at this time it seems like my only solution without digging massively deep. I will leave more feedback here when i have a solution. (it is essential i get this working)

Comment: for anyone having the same issue as me and downgrading does not work, here is an example of an interceptor for retrying requests 

https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/L5-node-client-interceptors.md#examples

Comment: @JayP thanks for sharing knowledge